# Signature is invalid with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature

I have two CSC based credentials from different TSPs(say CredA and CredB).I am trying to perform PDF Signing using both credentials.
I have implemented the same in two ways, one with `PDFBox` and other using `Itext`.

CredA works with below `PDFBox`implementation but fails with `Itext` implementation.

```
    public static void testSign(InputStream is, PDDocument document, Certificate[] certificateChain, String accessToken) throws Exception {
        try (
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("/[filepath]/", "Signed.pdf"));
        ) {
            PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();

            signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
            signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ETSI_CADES_DETACHED);
            signature.setName("Test Name");
            signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());

            SignatureOptions signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
            signatureOptions.setPage(0);

            document.addSignature(signature, signatureOptions);
            ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(output);

            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certificateChain[0];

            ESSCertIDv2 certid = new ESSCertIDv2(
                    new AlgorithmIdentifier(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha256),
                    MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(cert.getEncoded())
            );
            SigningCertificateV2 sigcert = new SigningCertificateV2(certid);
            Attribute attr = new Attribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signingCertificateV2, new DERSet(sigcert));

            ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
            v.add(attr);
            AttributeTable atttributeTable = new AttributeTable(v);
            CMSAttributeTableGenerator attrGen = new DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(atttributeTable);

            org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate cert2 = org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate.getInstance(ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(cert.getEncoded()));
            JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder sigb = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build());
            sigb.setSignedAttributeGenerator(attrGen);

            ContentSigner contentSigner = new ContentSigner() {
                private MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                private OutputStream stream = OutputStreamFactory.createStream(digest);
                @Override
                public byte[] getSignature() {
                    try {

                        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
                        int count;

                        while ((count = is.read(b)) > 0) {
                            digest.update(b, 0, count);
                        }
                        byte[] hashBytes = digest.digest();

                        java.util.Base64.Encoder encoder = java.util.Base64.getEncoder();
                        List<String> hash = Arrays.asList(encoder.encodeToString(hashBytes));
                        byte[] signedHash = signHash(accessToken, hash);
                        return signedHash;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Exception while signing", e);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
                    return stream;
                }

                @Override
                public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier() {
                    return new AlgorithmIdentifier(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.1.11"));
                }
            };

            CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
            gen.addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(Arrays.asList(certificateChain)));
            gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(sigb.build(contentSigner, new X509CertificateHolder(cert2)));


            final CMSProcessableByteArray content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(
                    IOUtils.toByteArray(externalSigning.getContent()));
            CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(content, false);

            byte[] cmsSignature = signedData.getEncoded();
            externalSigning.setSignature(cmsSignature);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] signHash(String accessToken, List hash) throws Exception {

        String SAD = "";
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        //CredentialsAuthorize API
        JSONObject requestHeaderCredentialsAuthorize = new JSONObject();
        requestHeaderCredentialsAuthorize.put("Content-type", "application/json");
        requestHeaderCredentialsAuthorize.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        JSONObject requestPayloadCredentialsAuthorize = new JSONObject();
        requestPayloadCredentialsAuthorize.put("credentialID", keyID);
        requestPayloadCredentialsAuthorize.put("numSignatures", "1");
        requestPayloadCredentialsAuthorize.put("PIN", SecretPIN);

        JSONArray hashArray = new JSONArray();
        hashArray.add(hash.get(0));
        requestPayloadCredentialsAuthorize.put("hash", hashArray);

        JSONObject credentialsAuthorizeResponse = PosttoHttpURLConnection.getResponseHTTP(CSC_CredentialsAuthorize_URL, requestPayloadCredentialsAuthorize.toString(), requestHeaderCredentialsAuthorize);
        if (credentialsAuthorizeResponse != null) {
            JSONObject credentialsAuthorizeResponseObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(credentialsAuthorizeResponse.get("Response").toString());
            if (credentialsAuthorizeResponse.get("StatusCode").toString().equals("200")) {
                SAD = credentialsAuthorizeResponseObject.get("SAD") == null ? "" : credentialsAuthorizeResponseObject.get("SAD").toString();
                String expires_in = credentialsAuthorizeResponseObject.get("expires_in") == null ? "" : credentialsAuthorizeResponseObject.get("expires_in").toString();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        String keyAlgorithm = "SHA256withRSA";
        //signHash API
        JSONObject requestHeadersignHash = new JSONObject();
        requestHeadersignHash.put("Content-type", "application/json");
        requestHeadersignHash.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        JSONObject requestPayloadsignHash = new JSONObject();
        requestPayloadsignHash.put("credentialID", keyID);
        requestPayloadsignHash.put("SAD", SAD);
        requestPayloadsignHash.put("hashAlgo", "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1");
        requestPayloadsignHash.put("signAlgo", "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1");
        requestPayloadsignHash.put("signAlgoParams", keyAlgorithm);
        JSONArray signHashArray = new JSONArray();
        signHashArray.add(hash.get(0));
        requestPayloadsignHash.put("hash", signHashArray);

        JSONObject signHashResponse = PosttoHttpURLConnection.getResponseHTTP(CSC_signHash_URL, requestPayloadsignHash.toString(), requestHeadersignHash);
        if (signHashResponse != null) {
            JSONObject signHashResponseObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(signHashResponse.get("Response").toString());
            if (signHashResponse.get("StatusCode").toString().equals("200")) {
                JSONArray signedHashArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(signHashResponseObject.get("signatures").toString());
                String rawSignature = signedHashArray.get(0).toString();
                byte[] signatureBytes = org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.decode(rawSignature);
                return signatureBytes;
            }
        }
                return null;
    }
```

CredB works with below `IText` implementation but fails with above `PDFBox` implementation.

```
            String access_token = getAccessTokenAPI();
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


            String CredentialsInfoAlgoValue = "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1";
            JSONArray certificates = getCredentialsInfoAPI();

            //Hash Doc
            int contentEstimated = 32768;
            PdfReader readerpdf = new PdfReader(filePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream fout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfStamper stamperpdf = PdfStamper.createSignature(readerpdf, fout, '\0', null, true);
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamperpdf.getSignatureAppearance();
            appearance.setReason("Demo");
            appearance.setLocation("10.80.100.46");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
            appearance.setSignDate(cal);
            appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
            appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED);
            appearance.setImage(null);

            appearance.setAcro6Layers(false);
            String[] str = "285,300,415,370".split(",");
            Float[] intarray = new Float[str.length];
            int i = 0;
            for (String strs : str) {
                intarray[i] = Float.parseFloat(strs.trim());
                i++;
            }

            int[] pages = {Integer.parseInt("1")};
            List<Rectangle> listRectangle = new ArrayList<>();
            listRectangle.add(new Rectangle(intarray[0], intarray[1], intarray[2], intarray[3]));
            appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(intarray[0], intarray[1], intarray[2], intarray[3]), pages[0], null);
            HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<PdfName, Integer>();
            exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new Integer(contentEstimated * 2 + 2));
            PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
            dic.setReason(appearance.getReason());
            dic.setLocation(appearance.getLocation());
            dic.setContact(appearance.getContact());
            Calendar calDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            dic.setDate(new PdfDate(calDate));
            appearance.setCryptoDictionary(dic);
            appearance.setLayer2Text("Signed by: " + "Demo User" + " \nReason: Demo");
            appearance.setLayer2Font(new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK));
            appearance.preClose(exc);

            Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[certificates.size()];
            int c = 1;
            for (int k = 0; k < certificates.size(); k++) {
                X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.decode(certificates.get(k).toString().getBytes())));
                String subject = getSubjectType(cert);
                if (subject.equalsIgnoreCase("EndEntity")) {
                    chain[0] = cert;
                } else {
                    chain[c++] = cert;
                }
            }

            ExternalDigest externalDigest = new ExternalDigest() {
                public MessageDigest getMessageDigest(String hashAlgorithm)
                        throws GeneralSecurityException {
                    return DigestAlgorithms.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm, null);
                }
            };
            PdfPKCS7 sgn = null;
            byte hash[] = null;
            byte ocsp[] = null;

            InputStream data = appearance.getRangeStream();;
            if (CredentialsInfoAlgoValue.equals("1.2.840.10045.4.3.3")) {
                sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA384", null, externalDigest, false);
                hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, externalDigest.getMessageDigest("SHA384"));
            } else if (CredentialsInfoAlgoValue.equals("1.2.840.10045.4.3.4")) {
                sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA512", null, externalDigest, false);
                hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, externalDigest.getMessageDigest("SHA512"));
            } else {
                sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", null, externalDigest, false);
                hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, externalDigest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));
            }

            byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, calDate, ocsp, null, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);

            String stringDocumentHash = new String(org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.encode(sh));
            String SAD = getCredentialsAuthoriseAPI();
            
            String rawSignature = getSignHashAPI();
            byte[] signatureBytes = org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.decode(rawSignature);
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = fout;
            sgn.setExternalDigest(signatureBytes, null, "RSA");
            Collection<byte[]> crlBytes = null;
            TSAClient tsaClient = null;
            byte[] pkcs7 = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, calDate, tsaClient, ocsp, crlBytes, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
            byte[] paddedSig = new byte[32768];
            System.arraycopy(pkcs7, 0, paddedSig, 0, pkcs7.length);
            PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
            dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).setHexWriting(true));
            appearance.close(dic2);

            System.out.println("Signed PDF Document saved at: " + filePath + "_signed.pdf");
            String outputFile1 = filePath+"_signed.pdf";
            Path signedFile = Paths.get(outputFile1);
            Files.write(signedFile, os.toByteArray());
            return;
```

Can anyone please help me in identifying the difference between both implementations (apart from appearance). I want to run both CredA and CredB using `PDFBox` implementation, but CredB works only with `IText` and fails with `PDFBox` with error as `Invalid Signature(Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed)`.

Comment: @mkl Please suggest.

Comment: Can you share an example PDF signed by your code? At first glance the pdfbox signing code looks OK, so the issue most likely is a small detail. Analyzing the signed PDF could help identifying that detail.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for your response. I figured out that PDFBox sample works for some other credential. I have updated the question. Can you please check now. I want my both credentials to work with PDFBox. One works with IText, other works with PDFBox.

Comment: If it works for some credentials and not for others, it's even more important to analyze the signed documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your iText based code and your PDFBox based code is that

- in the former case (iText), you send the *actual* authenticated attributes for signing (you call the carrier object `stringDocumentHash` but it's actually a string containing the authenticated attributes and the document hash is but one of those attributes), but
- in the latter case (PDFBox), you send *a hash of* the data for signing. (In this case it is unclear in your code what that data in the `InputStream is` is.)

Thus, apparently the CredB TSP (which works with iText) expects you to send the actual bytes to sign and itself calculates a hash thereof, and the CredA TSP (which works with PDFBox) expects you to send a hash of the bytes to sign and uses that value as is.

To enable your PDFBox code to work for both TSPs, you either have to change your code to only optionally hash the authenticated bytes (and request hashing based on the TSP used), or you have to orchestrate your CredB access to also expect the raw data to sign, not a hash thereof.

---

Unfortunately, when copying the code into your question, some errors slipped into both versions, rendering them not compilable. Thus, the above analysis only loosely is based on that code. Instead it's mostly based on the example file you provided.

---

By the way, the subject of the signer certificate, `...,PostalCode=\ xxxx,ST=\ xxxxx,...`, is asking for trouble with the blanks at the beginning of the `PostalCode` and `ST` entries...

---

PS: Please try the following `ContentSigner` instead of the one in your code for signing runs with CredB and PDFBox:

```java
ContentSigner contentSigner = new ContentSigner() {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Override
    public byte[] getSignature() {
        try {
            java.util.Base64.Encoder encoder = java.util.Base64.getEncoder();
            List<String> hash = Arrays.asList(encoder.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray()));
            byte[] signedHash = signHash(accessToken, hash);
            return signedHash;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception while signing", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return stream;
    }

    @Override
    public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier() {
        return new AlgorithmIdentifier(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.1.11"));
    }
}
```

As I neither have a runnable version of your code nor the CredB credentials (or equivalent ones), I cannot test myself.

Comment: Thanks @mkl for this detailed analysis. "Inputstream is" is the document stream only. But, as part of my debugging, I have already tried replacing the hash generation part of PDFBox approach with IText one. I added the code where we generate signedAttributes with ExternalDigest in the place of generating hash digest in PDFBox implementation. It still fails with same error.

Comment: *'"Inputstream is" is the document stream only.'* - you don't need that stream here. Actually, I assume you read that stream to the end before, so it behaves like an empty stream here.

Comment: *"Please check the updated file with the suggested fix"* - I cannot recognize what the hash value has been calculated here from. I'll add an alternative `ContentSigner` to my answer for you to try with PDFBox and CredB.

Comment: Thanks @mkl. Please let me know after adding. Looking forward to learn more from you.

Comment: *"Please let me know after adding. "* - It's already been added.

Comment: *"It worked."* - Great! But remember, depending on the credentials you'll have to select the `ContentSigner` implementation to use. You might want to try and determine that implementation by looking into some values the service API can return as self-description.

Comment: yes, will handle that conditionally. Also, when used the same certificate for certification signature instead of approval signature, acrobat says: "The validity of document certification is UNKNOWN. The author could not be verified." Could it be a certificate level restriction that it only allows approval signature? And How the spaces in state and pincode can impact?

Comment: *"Could it be a certificate level restriction that it only allows approval signature?"* - I'd need an example file to analyze. The PDF specification does *not* require different certificates for certification vs. approval signatures. Adobe, though, sometimes have their own ideas. *"And How the spaces in state and pincode can impact?"* - sloppy certificate processing software may drop such spaces during processing in some contexts and then fail to identify your certificate correctly. I.e. you may get surprising validation failures

Comment: The certificate you used is issued by some test CA which neither is on the AATL nor on the EUTL. Thus, Adobe Acrobat will always display "The author could not be identified". UNLESS you configured Adobe Acrobat to trust a certificate from that certificate chain, either explicitly (in Adobe Acrobat settings) or implicitly (in OS settings). When explicitly configuring that trust, you can select whether the trust is only for regular signatures or also for certification signatures. Similarly you can configure what OS certificates are trusted for.

Comment: Beware, though, this differentiation is Adobe Acrobat specific, it is not prescribed by the PDF specification.  Other PDF processors may or may not differentiate similarly.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, It worked. In my machine it was not trusted for certifying signtures.

Comment: If we talk about above issue of sending hash in different form for CredA and CredB, which one is CSC compliant and which one is not?

Comment: *"which one is CSC compliant and which one is not?"* - It _looks like_ CredA is more compliant: the CSC `/csc/v1/signatures/signHash` method is specified to expect a hash to be signed, not the raw data. As the code you shared is not runnable, though, and as I don't have those credentials, I cannot truly test.