# PDFBox - Signing a PDF using an external service (document has been altered or corrupted)

Tags: java, pdf, hash, pdfbox

I want to sign a document with using an external API. You can send an hash to that service and get a signed hash back. You also get the complete certificate chain which was used by the service. (As you can see I also add a visual signature, but it works fine and can be ignored in this case, I just added it for context as you can see the visuals in the example PDF)

After loads of trial and error, this is the best result I can produce, where the signature is only invalid because of "The document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed".

For further inspection a link to a PDF signed by this code: https://pdfhost.io/v/5lM7xk4SX_testing

And here is the code responsible for signing:

```java
  public void signPdf(String filePath, String outfilePath, Certificate[] chain, SignatureAppearance signatureAppearance) {
    try (
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outfilePath);
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath))
    ) {
      PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
      signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
      signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
      signature.setName(signatureAppearance.getSignerName());
      signature.setReason("Testing purposes");
      signature.setLocation("Test Location");
      signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());

      Rectangle2D humanRect = new Rectangle2D.Float(signatureAppearance.getSignatureXLocation(), signatureAppearance.getSignatureYLocation(), 200, 50);
      PDRectangle rect = createSignatureRectangle(document, humanRect);

      SignatureOptions options = new SignatureOptions();
      options.setPage(0);
      options.setVisualSignature(createVisualSignatureTemplate(document, 0, rect, signature, signatureAppearance));
      document.addSignature(signature, null, options);

      CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
      Store certStore = new JcaCertStore(Arrays.stream(chain).toList());
      X509Certificate signerCert = (X509Certificate) chain[0];
      ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(output);
      byte[] pdfHash = new SHA256.Digest().digest(externalSigning.getContent().readAllBytes());

      ContentSigner contentSigner = new ContentSigner() {
        private final OutputStream stream = OutputStreamFactory.createStream(new SHA256.Digest());

        @Override
        public byte[] getSignature() {
          try {
            return webAPIService.getSignedHash(bytesToHex(pdfHash)).getBytes();
          } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception while signing", e);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
          return stream;
        }

        @Override
        public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier() {
          return new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha256WithRSAEncryption);
        }
      };

      gen.addCertificates(certStore);
      gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
          new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
              new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()).build())
              .build(contentSigner, signerCert));

      CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(pdfHash);
      CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg, false);

      byte[] cmsSignature = signedData.getEncoded();
      externalSigning.setSignature(cmsSignature);
    } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (OperatorCreationException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (CMSException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
      sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

I'm guessing that there is something wrong with how I handle the contentSigner, especially how the hash from the pdf is handed into it. Then the hash of the PDF does not match the signed-hash or something similar. But I cannot find the proper way to do it.

I also tried to follow the example here (http://www.java2s.com/example/java-api/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/digitalsignature/externalsigningsupport/getcontent-0-0.html) where only the `ExternalSigningSupport` is used. There I replaced the `sign` call with my `getSignedHash`. But then I wouldn't even get a valid signers entity. I guess in the `sign` method there is more then just a signed hash returned.

Comment: What viewer are you using?  I can see the PDF fine.

Comment: Using Adobe Acrobat Reader it tells me that the Signature is invalid

Comment: Does the `ContentSigner` implementation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77389304/1729265) work for you? If you don't hash the `externalSigning.getContent()` yourself, that is. The `CMSSignedDataGenerator` will do that for you.

Comment: Sadly, no luck. The ContentSigner implementation produces the same result.
Funny enough, if I remove the self hashed variable `pdfHash` and fill the `CMSTypedData` the way like the OP of the other question - even the Signers identity is not valid anymore. (here is a gist of my current method: https://gist.github.com/wgnrd/e6fcb6155795014db10fd482bdb40133)

Comment: Can you share an example PDF signed by your code for analysis?

Comment: Your certificate has a RSA/3072 public key but your signature value has a length of 512 bytes, i.e. 4096 bits. That doesn't match. Your `webAPIService.getSignedHash(...).getBytes()` call apparently signs using some RSA/4096 key, i.e. not your key...

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the insight. Just to clarify this, the response of the webAPI (length of 4096bits) call does not match the expected format of the certificate (3072 bits) in the pdf?
I see in the one of the possible certificate chains, that the key lengths are [3072, 4096, 4096]. 
But even if I use a different chain [4096, 4096] I get the same result. Could you tell me how you are looking into a PDF to see the length of the signature and the public key of the certificate. Are you using RUPS for that?

Comment: *"the response of the webAPI (length of 4096bits) call does not match the expected format of the certificate (3072 bits) in the pdf?"* - Yes. This may mean (as mentioned in my previous comment) that the value is created by the wrong key. But it might also mean that the value is not the plain signature but somehow encoded. Thus, are you sure your API returns you the plain signature value, or could it actually be a base64 encoded signature value? In that case the lengths would match, base64 decoding generates 3 bytes for 4 characters, so you would get a 3072 bit value from the 4096 bit data...

Comment: *"Could you tell me how you are looking into a PDF to see the length of the signature and the public key of the certificate."* - For the length of the public key you can simply use Adobe Acrobat, from the _Signature Panel_ open the _Signature Properties_ of the signature in question; from there press _Show Signer's Certificate_; in the _Certificate Viewer_ select the _Details_ tab and scroll down to _Public key_. See [this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw0rL.png).

Comment: For the length of the signature I use a small tool to extract the signature containers embedded in the signature values, [SignatureExtractor](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/SignatureExtractor.java), but you can do the same using RUPS. Then I open the signature container in an ASN.1 viewer, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/ , and inspect it. In case of your signature I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha70p.png).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know which tools you are using. I tried to decode the returned value like `java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(webAPIService.getSignedHash(hash));` The result is sadly the same. I don't have extensive documentation about the return of the API call, but it would make sense that the returned value is encoded. 
I also came across this validation tool: https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/validation - it states that "The signed attribute: 'signing-certificate' is absent!"

Comment: *"The result is sadly the same."* - It is still the wrong size? That is weird... You should debug closely into what is sent and what is returned by each call during signing. *" I also came across this validation tool: ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/validation - it states that "The signed attribute: 'signing-certificate' is absent!""* - Well, you don't create a PAdES signature but a simple old-style one. Thus it is not surprising that eSig DSS does not accept your signature.

Comment: *"In case you want to look at the updated PDF with the decoded signature: pdfhost.io/v/LZtrYO7Yq_dummy_pdf "* - ah, but that's already much better: Not only does the size of your signature now match the key, the signature can even be decoded with the public key. What is wrong is that the alleged hash value in the encrypted signature value is 151 bytes long - that's much too long. Comparing it to the rest of the signature, though, one can recognize those bytes: They are the signed attributes themselves, not their hash as it should be! Also the alleged document hash is the hash of the hash.

Comment: In the gist version of your code, in `getSignature()` of your `ContentSigner` you take the contents of the `ByteArrayOutputStream stream`, base64 encode them and send them for signing. Apparently your signing API does not expect the full data to sign but actually expects you to hash it. Thus, before base64 encoding calculate the hash of the stream contents and send that (after base64 encoding) for signing.

Comment: In the gist version of your code I cannot understand the double-hashing of the document data. Could it be that that code there is not up to date?

Comment: *"I didn't know there where different types of signature. Is it possible to create a PAdES signature with PDFBox. I cannot find any examples to that."* - well, essentially you need to add an extra signed attribute (ESS CertID v2) and use a different subfilter value. But if you really want to do PAdES signatures, you should consider looking into eSig DSS. That library is good for CAdES/PAdES/XAdES signature processing. For PAdES it uses PDFBox (or optionally OpenPdf) for PDF processing but it does all the PAdES extras for you. In particular if you eventually want to create LT or LTA signatures.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should now hash something (like for the API which doesn't expect the full data) or if I have something hash twice. I have now updated the gist to my latest understanding of your description. But could you ellaborate a little more on how I can integrate a PAdES signature here? An example would be perfect. 
Furthermore I tried to switch the order of operations (first encode the stream and then hash it, vice versa) but looking at it in Adobe I always get the same error message.

Comment: You do it in the wrong order: In `getSignature()` of your `ContentSigner` you now first base64 encode the data-to-sign, then you hash that string. But that's not what you want here, You want to hash the data-to-sign and then base64 encode the hash value for transmission.

Comment: Ok. But as I stated, I tried both orders, but they produced both produce an invalid signature.

Comment: Please try again with first hashing, then base64 encoding, and share the result.

Comment: *"Sure. I updated the gist and here is the result:"* - Great, the signature bytes now are correct, merely the document hash is double hashed: You hash explicitly and the BouncyCastle `CMSSignedDataGenerator` hashes again. Thus, don't hash the `externalSigning.getContent().readAllBytes()` bytes but feed them as-is into the `CMSProcessableByteArray`. As soon as that works we can update that to create PAdES baseline B signatures.

Comment: @Wgnrd Have you meanwhile tested your code without that extra hashing?

Comment: Great! I'll turn the changes we applied into an actual answer. Thereafter we can have a look at what is necessary to change your code for actual PAdES signatures.

Comment: Perfect. Ty for writing up the journey. I'll remove my comments linking to old PDFs with broken signatures.

Comment: Concerning making your signatures PAdES signatures, do you want to discuss that in the context of this question or if a new question? Or did that turn out unnecessary?

Comment: I mean, it would be awesome if you could lead me to a working example. But for future examples, I think it's better if I create another question starting from the current working code.

Comment: As discussed - https://stackoverflow.com/q/77931839/7099387

Comment: *"As discussed ..."* - ah, great, I overlooked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fixing the code

In comments to the question example files signed by different versions of the code have been analyzed and some errors in the signing code have been identified and fixed, resulting in valid signature.

The starting state of the code was not the code in the question, though, it meanwhile had changed to the first revision of the code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wgnrd/e6fcb6155795014db10fd482bdb40133).

### Processing the signature in the signing API response

In the first example file one issue leapt to the eye: the signer certificate has a RSA/3072 public key but the signature value had a length of 512 bytes, i.e. 4096 bits. This obviously doesn't match.

Possible causes include that the signing API actually signed with a private key not corresponding to the alleged signer certificate. Another possible cause was that the bytes returned by `webAPIService.getSignedHash` are not yet the plain signature bytes to use but have to be processed somehow first.

As it turned out, the latter case was the cause here: the bytes returned by `webAPIService.getSignedHash` actually are the base64 encoded signature bytes, for use here they needed to be base64 decoded. Base64 encoding enlarges the data by a 4:3 ratio, so after decoding the size of signature and key matched.

So in

```java
public byte[] getSignature() {
  try {
    java.util.Base64.Encoder encoder = java.util.Base64.getEncoder();
    String hash = encoder.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray());
    return webAPIService.getSignedHash(hash).getBytes();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Exception while signing", e);
  }
}
```

the `return` line was replaced by

```java
    return java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(webAPIService.getSignedHash(hash));
```

Now the final signed hash can be successfully decrypted using the public key in the signer certificate and the result thereof can successfully be parsed, which are checks one can make for RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signatures. Thus, now it was clear that the signing API response was properly processed.

## Sending the data to sign in the signing API request

The next apparent issue was that the alleged hash value in the decrypted signature value was 151 bytes long. This is much too large, for SHA256 (as claimed by the code) that hash should be 32 bytes long.

Comparing it to the rest of the signature, though, one could recognize those bytes: They were the signed attributes themselves, not their hash as it should have been! Apparently the signing API as argument of `webAPIService.getSignedHash` expects the hash to sign, not the original data.

Thus, the `getSignature` method was further changed to hash the signed attributes and send the hash to the API:

```java
public byte[] getSignature() {
  try {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

    byte[] hashBytes = digest.digest(stream.toByteArray()); // hashing the string
    String hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashBytes); // Base64 encoding

    return java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(webAPIService.getSignedHash(hash));
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Exception while signing", e);
  }
}
```

With this change in place, the signature bytes correctly signed the signed attributes.

### Providing the hash of the signed document ranges

Even after fixing the signature of the signed attributes the signature was invalid: The message-digest signed attribute value was incorrect.

As it turned out, the value of that attribute was not the hash of the signed document ranges but the hash of the hash! This happened because the code both hashed explicitly itself and then the BouncyCastle `CMSSignedDataGenerator` hashed again. Thus, the explicit hashing in the code needed to be removed,

```java
ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(output);
byte[] pdfHash = new SHA256.Digest().digest(externalSigning.getContent().readAllBytes());
...
CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(pdfHash);
CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg, false);
```

was replaced by

```java
ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(output);
byte[] pdfHash = externalSigning.getContent().readAllBytes();
...
CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(pdfHash);
CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg, false);
```

With this change in place, the signature finally is valid!

(Albeit the variable name `pdfHash` is misleading, but that surely will be cleaned up eventually...)